# Multiple table query - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm  new to mysql so I don't know yet how to make queries joining multiple tables so I need some help making this query.

So I have these tables:

Products

```
| id         | category    | description  |    brand     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |    desktops |    Hp example|     HP       |
| 2          |    laptops  |  asus example|       ASUS   |
```

Stores

```
| id         | location    | Brands(physical stores) | 
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------------------:|
| 1          |    liverpool|    currys               |    
| 2          |    london   | novatech                | 
| 3          |    bristol  | novatech                |
```

products_stores

```
| id_product | id_store    | price   | 
|:-----------|------------:|:-------:|
| 1          |    2        |    700  |    
| 2          |    3        |   400   | 
| 2          |    1        |   300   |
```

So, I want a query to get data and organize it like this (supposing I want all data):

```
| category    | description  |    brand     |   store      |  location  |   price   |
|:------------|-------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:----------:|:---------:|
|    desktops |    Hp example|     HP       |    novatech  |  london    |   700     |
|    laptops  |  asus example|       ASUS   |    novatech  |  bristol   |   400     |
|    laptops  |  asus example|       ASUS   |    currys    |  liverpool |   300     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select products.category, products.description, products.brand, stores.brands, stores.location, products_stores.price
from products_stores
inner join stores on stores.id = products_stores.stores_id
inner join products on products.id = products_stores.products_id
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1ae2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) (more particularly `INNER JOIN` and make sure that the `store` column isn't called `Brands(physical stores)` though. If it's called `brands`, then simply change it in the query:

```
SELECT
    pr.category,
    pr.description,
    pr.brand,
    st.store,
    st.location,
    ps.price
FROM
    `products_stores` as `ps`
INNER JOIN
    `products` as `pr`
ON
    pr.id = ps.id_product
INNER JOIN
    `stores` as `st`
ON
    st.id = ps.id_store
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.category, p.description, p.brand, s.Brands as store, s.location, ps.price 
    FROM Products p, Stores s, products_stores ps 
         WHERE p.id = ps.id_product AND s.id = ps.id_store;
```

Use above query.